# Java Server Closing Code

Tags: java, sockets

So I'm making a program to implement some cross-server protocol. However, we have to edit our own server object to overwrite some server methods. One of these is the 'close' method.

Now I understand that all ServerSockets and Sockets should call their close() method, and I've looped through another array of sockets, calling all of their corresponding close() methods.

However, when run, my program doesn't seem to close. In the terminal window, it just keeps a blank line, not returning control to the normal shell.

I'm not sure why this is happening, and I can only conclude it is something wrong in my code? Any help would be really appreciated (I've attached code to make my problem clearer).

The Close method for the server:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (lastSS != null) {
        lastSS.close();
    }
    if (nextSS != null) {
        nextSS.close(); 
    }
    if (acceptSS != null) {
        acceptSS.close();
    }
    if (baseSS != null) {
        baseSS.close();
    }
    if (returnSock != null) { 
        returnSock.close();   
    }
    if (baseGetSock != null) {
        baseGetSock.close();
    }
    if (commSocks != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<commSocks.length; i++) {
            if (commSocks[i] != null) {
            commSocks[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
    super.close();
```

And the actual call to the server.close() :

```
    try{
       //Some code here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        server.close();
    }
```

Comment: if you want to close the clients when the server is closed, I suggest you don't override the close method but instead close the clients in the main method, or better let the clients close themselves based on a timeout

Comment: The client closes perfectly fine, it's just the main servers. I have had to make several for this project, but they don't seem to close properly.

Comment: The problem is obviously with the code you *haven't* posted. Are the connection-handling threads exiting? Do they handle closure of their sockets correcty? Ditto the accept thread? Are there any other non-daemon threads?

Comment: @CAFC_Sam how did you know they don't close properly ? by seeing that the server processes didn't disappear in "Task manager"/"ps" ? if the answer is "yes" then you're mixing between `socket.close()` and the termination of threads

Comment: `socket.close` would only close the connection, it won't end the server process, the server process would end by the end of main method and the end of non-daemon threads unless as @EJP said you have threads issues